# checking if a streaming server is up using bash?

Tags: bash

I use Ubuntu and am trying to write a script that makes the following:
-test if an audio stream works
-if not, send an email.

I have tried the following code (running as a cron job every 10 minutes), which 'works' if I supply the wrong pw e.g.(it sends an email then), but does nothing if the actual server is down (tested by killing the server). any ideas on how to fix the script?
Thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
#servertest.sh


username=user1
password=xyz


url="http://wwww.streamingaudioserver.com -passwd $password -user $username"

mplayer $url &
sleep 5

test=$(pgrep -c mplayer)

if [ $test = 0 ]; then
    #server is down!
    mailfile="downmail.txt"
    /usr/sbin/ssmtp test@maildomain.com < "/home/test/$mailfile"  
fi

killall mplayer
sleep 5

exit
```

Comment: when u say kill the server, do you mean killing the process or actually shutting down the server?

Comment: shutting down the server, i.e. 'simulating' a server that is down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$mailfile="downmail.txt"
```

remove the dollar sign and that should do it.

You should be getting error messages in your cron log or emails to the crontab owner complaining about a command not found or no such file.

**Edit:**

Does your script work if run from the command line (with the stream down) rather than cron?

Try using `set -x` (or `#!/bin/bash -x`) in the script to turn on tracing or use `echo "PID: $$, value of \$test: $test" > /tmp/script.out` after the assignment to see if you're getting the zero you're expecting.

Also, try an `ssmtp` command outside the `if` to make sure it's working (but I think you already said it is under some circumstances).

Try your script without ever starting mplayer.

Comment: yes you are right, I changed it. That was a typo when I changed the posting. In my bash script it was correct. The problem with the script is that it sends a 'server down' email when it can not connect to the streaming server because of an incorrect password to the stream, but not if the stream itself is down.

Comment: @user644543: Does your script work if run from the command line (with the stram down) rather than cron? Try using `set -x` (or `#!/bin/bash -x`) in the script to turn on tracing or use `echo "PID: $$, value of \$test: $test" > /tmp/script.out` after the assignment to see if you're getting the zero you're expecting. Also, try an `ssmtp` command outside the `if` to make sure it's working (but I think you already said it is under some circumstances). Try your script without ever starting `mplayer`.

Comment: great advice. that worked, so now I know that it is the mailing function that is not working properly. thanks!

Comment: @user644543: I added to contents of my comment to my answer. If you would like, you can mark it as accepted.